# How does this code of list comprehension with multiple variables assigned works

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings. I need to parse and convert the string into floats and use that for a calculation.

After multiple attempts, I figured out the easiest way to do this.

```
List=["1x+1y+0","1x-1y+0","1x+0y-3","0x+1y-0.5"]
```

I need to extract the numerical coefficients of x and y
I used:

```
for coef in re.split('x|y', line):
     float(coeff)
```

This was not serving the purpose and then I found out that,

```
for line in list:
    a,b,c = [float(coef) for coef in re.split('x|y', line)]
```

this code works. 
If I do

```
a=[float(coeff) for coeff in re.split('x|y',lines)]
```

then a is a list with coefficients of the line

```
[1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
[1.0, -1.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, -3.0]
[0.0, 1.0, -0.5]
```

However, I am struggling to understand the logic. Here we used list comprehension. How can we assign multiple variables in a list comprehension? Is the way it works as follows:
for each string element in the list, it splits the string and converts into float. And then assign the three numbers resulting from the operation to three numbers.
But how is that if we assign only one variable it is a list, but if we assign multiple variables the type is changing?

I am sorry if the question is too basic. Am new to python hence the doubt.

Comment: As a comment, please don't use `list` as the variable name for a list. You'll overwrite the built-in list function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a, b, c = x` is called [sequence unpacking](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Python/Statement/What_is_sequence_unpacking_in_Python.htm). It is (almost) equivalent to:

```
a = x[0]
b = x[1]
c = x[2]
```

So `a,b,c = [float(coef) for coef in re.split('x|y', line)]` actually means:

```
x = [float(coef) for coef in re.split('x|y', line)]
a = x[0]
b = x[1]
c = x[2]
```

But `a = x` is not unpacking - it's just normal assignment: it makes `a` reference `x`. The difference: in the first case you assign a list to three variables, each "gets" one item of the list. In the second case, you assign a list to one variable and that variable "gets" the whole list. Assigning a list of three numbers to two variables (`a, b = [1, 2, 3]`) is invalid - you get an error message saying that there are too many values to unpack.